# Creating a list via a constructor C#

Tags: c#

I have a positive and negative Magic 8 ball file. Both are connected to the first file. When I run both, I get positive answers. I want for the negative file to get only negative answers. I want to use the methods I have.

This leads to the issue that I'm running into is that the Magic8Ball needs to take a list of alternate answers to change the feel of the game. I need to do this via a constructor. In the program, I need to initialize a list of negative answers and pass it into the magic8ball as a parameter to the constructor. I’m confused on how I might do that. Once I’m able to create these negatives answers, I can take them and use them in my negative file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Magic8Ball_Logic
{

    public class Magic8Ball
    {
        private List<string> _answers;
        private string randomString;

        public Magic8Ball()
        {
            _answers = new List<string>();
            _answers.Add("It is certain.");
            _answers.Add("It is decidedly so.");
            _answers.Add("Without a doubt.");
        }

        public Magic8Ball(List<string> answers)
        {
            //I won't use the 20 default.  use the ones passed in .
            _answers = answers;
        }

        public void Shake()
        {
            //picking the index of the answer to show the user
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next(_answers.Count);
            randomString = _answers[index];
        }

        public string GetAnswer()
        {
            //using the index picked by shake to return the answer
            //return "";
            return randomString;
        }

        public int AnswerCount
        {
            get { return _answers.Count; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
             return "" ;
        }
    }
}
```

ALTERNATIVE NEGATIVE ANSWERS FILE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string userAnswer = "";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Alternative Program!");
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball");
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
            Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
            Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
            Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
            Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball ball = new Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball();
            string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            do
            {
                if (input == "S")
                {
                    if (userAnswer != "")
                    {
                        //Call Method Shake()
                        ball.Shake();
                        Console.WriteLine("Searching the Mystic Realms(RAM) for the answer");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                        Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                        Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                        Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                        Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                        input = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You must ask a question first before shaking the Magic 8 Ball.");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                        Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                        Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                        Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                        Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                        input = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                else if (input == "A")
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("What is your Question?");
                    userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                    Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                    Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                    Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                    Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (input == "G") //TODO: Make sure you have shaken the 8 ball
                {
                    if (userAnswer == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Question Before Asking For An Answer.");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                        Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                        Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                        Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                        Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                        input = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Call Method GetAnswer()
                        string ballAnswer = ball.GetAnswer();
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("The answer to your question " + input + " is " + ballAnswer);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                        Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                        Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                        Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                        Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                        input = Console.ReadLine();
                        //TODO: Clear userAnswer
                        userAnswer = "";
                    }
                }
            } while (input != "E");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code would you create a `Magic8Ball` to display the pre-existing good answers? Is this a console application, or are you using WinForms, etc?

Comment: This is a console

Comment: I added the negative file, it is the same as my positive one. So currently when I run both, I get the positive answers. I want the negative answers though. I haven't created those yet due to being confused on the code

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see a place where the negative answers can fit. When do you intend for them to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a console application, I'd do it in the `Program.Main` method.

```c
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> badAnswers = new List<string>() { "It is not so", "Outlook not so good" };

    var _8ball = new Magic8Ball(badAnswers);
    _8ball.Shake();
    Console.WriteLine(_8ball.GetAnswer());
}
```

Comment: I added this code above. I already have this part working. The issue that I'm running into is that the answers are all positive. I don't want to use those answers on this file, I want to use the new negative ones.

Comment: Where are the new negative ones? You haven't included them. 

If you want to include them you need to add them to your _answers list. 

Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would pass in the good/bad answers into the constructor of the magic

```
    var GoodAnswers = new List<string>();
    GoodAnswers.Add("It is certain.");
    GoodAnswers.Add("It is decidedly so.");
    GoodAnswers.Add("Without a doubt.");

    var NegativeAnswers = new List<string>();
    NegativeAnswers.Add("It is not certain.");
    NegativeAnswers.Add("It is not decidedly so.");
    NegativeAnswers.Add("With a doubt.");

    Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball ball = new Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball();

    if (SomeCondition)
    {
        ball = new Magic8Ball(GoodAnswers);
    }
    else
    {
        ball = new Magic8Ball(NegativeAnswers);
    }
```